# Updating Passwords with PHP

Tags: php, bcrypt, password-hash, php-password-hash

PHP >= 5.5 has the `password_hash` function to simplify hashing passwords. Normally they recommend something like:

```
pasword_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

to take advantages of any improvement is future versions. Currently the default algorithm is `bcrypt`.

The questions are:

- will stored password hashes be incompatible with a future implementation which uses a different algorithm?
- if so, is there any way of updating the data?

Thanks

Comment: No one really knows what the future will bring but if anything does change with the algorithm I am sure there will also be a way of conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the manual **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)**

The identifier, example being `$2y$`, identifies which hash was used and therefore allowing compatibility in the future when additional algorithms are added.

For a hash, the only way to update it **should** be after the user enters their password, you can recreate the hash using a new algorithm.

Comment: Yes, I’ve read the manual. The `$2$y` part simply qualifies the bcrypt with a salt and cost parameter. Of itself, it makes no mention of compatibility with future implements of `php_hash`.

Comment: If you use the password_verify function, it uses this identifier to validate the password.  `$2y$` means it is a bcrypt hash, so password_verify will use bcrypt to validate the given password against the hash. In the future, if you have a different identifier, password_verify will use that hash to validate the password ensuring compatibility...

Comment: I see it now: it specifically states: “The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash.” Thanks. That answers the question.